# noise floor estimation

Tags: discrete-signals, digital-communications

I want to estimate noise floor in the spectrum. I tested many methods using journals, but I couldn't find a stable method. Suggest that we have a spectrum consist of many signal and we want to estimate noise floor form signal.

[image]

Comment: Is that over a set of real measurements?

Comment: Every time I comment on one of your questions, it's deleted a couple hours later, and I still always comment the same: What's the *context* of this? Noise floor measurements depend on what kind of noise you're expecting, and what kind of signal you want to keep out of that measurement, and for what purpose that measurment is made.

Comment: So, if you could, for every question you ask, always describe your motivation for asking it, that would be a really easy but effective improvement to our ability to answer them :)

Comment: @Marcus Müller I think you haven't information about my questions, My questions are obvious and except of you no body has problem with them. Please don't worrisome.

Comment: @A_A In a simulation environment.

Comment: The floor is the bottom. The signal you can see is the content above the floor.

Answer (score 1):

You can get help best if you can share what kind of signal do you have. For example, in scenarios where you have a multipath channel time domain response or 'channel impulse response', you can use mdeian of median of windows as your noise floor.

Because 'channel impulse response' will have multiple narrow peaks in time domain corresponding to each path, therefore, using mean of the complete CIR would result in biasing due to the high amplitude peaks.

Median is a better choice to avoid biased results of noise floor but it will require sorting operation and based on the length of signal, that might be a problem and complexity increases as $O(N.logN)$.

So, in such scenario it is best to use average of median of windowed sub-sections of the signal. You divide the complete signal into windows of size 256 or 512 and compute median of these sub-sections which will be pretty fast and then take median/average of this vector of medians. That is a pretty good noise floor and works well in practical scenario as well.

Comment: I added A image in my question. How I can calculate noise floor in this image?

Comment: @VelmaBenedict the method I suggested will work fine with the kind of signal you have shown